# Log4j2 timebased and sizebased rolling file appender

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I want a strategy in log4j2 that log file should roll on timebased and sizebased both. Such that it should roll on daily basis and when size reaches max 10KB (For test purpose). For that i tried following example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="fileLogger" fileName="E:\\Aditya\LOGS\AppLog.log" filePattern="E:\\Aditya\LOGS\AppLog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10KB" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <appender-ref ref="fileLogger" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The problem with above config is it is rolling file every second. To solve this problem i changed

```
<RollingFile name="fileLogger" fileName="E:\\Aditya\LOGS\AppLog.log" filePattern="E:\\Aditya\LOGS\AppLog-%%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}-%%i.log">
```

TO

```
<RollingFile name="fileLogger" fileName="E:\\Aditya\LOGS\AppLog.log" filePattern="E:\\Aditya\LOGS\AppLog-%%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%%i.log">
```

Now another problem is my total log files are limiting to 7 files per day only. I dont know why this is happening as i have not provided such configuration. Can anyone help me to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your pattern. Just try these patterns. 
%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} or %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}

Check this :
[log4j patterns](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html)